# Does Java support Swift-like class extensions?

Tags: java, subclass, extension-methods

In Swift, you can create extension of existing class to add additional functions to the existing class whenever it is needed. This also helps to avoid creating a subclass of the existing class.

I was just wondering if there is a similar function exist in Java? or is it the only way to add additional methods to a existing Java class is to create a subclass of the existing class?

Comment: Not in Java. However not everyone is happy with that say in Scala. As it can hamper readability, maintainability. Typically one makes a class with functions, like XxxUtils or Xxxs. Inheritance has its own problems there (final classes, forced obsoleteness of old code, centralism = just one extension point).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, vanilla Java does not feature extension methods. However, [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) adds many useful features - including extension methods syntax - thanks to its annotations and bytecode generation.

You can use its [@ExtensionMethod](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod.html) annotations to "convert" existing static methods to extension methods. The first parameter of the static methods basically becomes `this`. For example, this is a valid Lombok-enhanced Java code:

```
import lombok.experimental.ExtensionMethod;

@ExtensionMethod({java.util.Arrays.class, Extensions.class})
public class ExtensionMethodExample {
  public String test() {
    int[] intArray = {5, 3, 8, 2};
    intArray.sort();

    String iAmNull = null;
    return iAmNull.or("hELlO, WORlD!".toTitleCase());
  }
}

class Extensions {
  public static <T> T or(T obj, T ifNull) {
    return obj != null ? obj : ifNull;
  }

  public static String toTitleCase(String in) {
    if (in.isEmpty()) return in;
    return "" + Character.toTitleCase(in.charAt(0)) +
        in.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Note that Lombok extension methods can be "invoked" on null objects - as long as the static method is null-safe, `NullPointerException` will not be thrown, as this is basically translated to static method call. Yes - it comes down to syntax sugar, but I guess this is still more readable than the usual static methods calls.

Aside from that, you can use some other JVM language with Java interoperability, if that's OK in your project. For example, [Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/) comes with [extension methods functionality](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html), as well as some useful extensions already defined in the standard library. Here's a [Kotlin and Lombok comparison](https://blog.frankel.ch/comparing-lombok-and-kotlin/).

Comment: I love lombok :) this is really still far cleaner/readable in swift, but at least we can do it (rather directly at that) in Java as well.

Answer (score 2):

The [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Java) is perhaps the closest match. It uses interface to maintain the type compatibility and composition to enhance the existing class' function. It's not the same principle as the one you're describing but might serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in other languages for JVM, like Scala, [Groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/ExpandoMetaClass.html) or Closure.

For example in Groovy:

```
List.metaClass.printSize = {
    println delegate.size()
}

[1,2,3].printSize() //prints 3
```

In Scala you can use `implicit class`:

```
implicit class PrefixedString(val s: String) {
   def prefix = "prefix_" + s 
}

"foo".prefix // returns "prefix_foo"
```

Please have a look at [this article.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jn5)

An important remark is that Groovy/Scala source code is intended to be compiled to Java bytecode so that the resulting classes can be used in Java code.

Comment: Besides, Lombok does some magic internally, but it _is_ Java, so saying that its "impossible" is not exactly true.

Comment: The Scala example should probably use an `implicit class` that `extends AnyVal`